# Bash alias permanent <without running bash or . ~/.bashrc>

Tags: bash, alias

I'm used to putting my alias in `.bashrc`, but Ubuntu suggests putting them in `.bash_aliases`.  So that's fine, I put my alias there in the `.bash_aliases` file.  However I want to run my aliases once I log in. In order to do this I need to run bash.  Looking around, I've read that I need to put them in `.bash_profiles` file. If that's the case I believe I need to edit some more files and I'm unclear from that perspective.

What is the simplest way to run aliases on Ubuntu server without running bash each time?  I could just run bash and be done with it, but that's one more command.

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you put your aliases in `.bash_aliases`, open `.bashrc` file, find and uncomment or add next lines:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Reload your session and check your new aliases.

Comment: It's there already (and yes it's un commented) hence the reason why I thought I wouldn't have to run bash after each reboot.

Comment: @rdcence What exactly do you run after each reboot? It can't be bash... Bash is the shell yhat you are using; check with `echo $SHELL` to understand.

Comment: Ah ha!  I thought for sure I was running bash, but I'm not (with this particular user)!  I'm running /bin/sh so now my question takes on a new form (sorry).  When I set up the new user (who needs this alias) I thought it would default to /bin/bash  So a) can you point me in the right direction to change the user to bash and b) how would I do this in the first place when I set up a new user?

Comment: You are probably right.  I should post this "new" question in the right spot.  Thanks again for getting me on the right track!

Comment: Update: Works perfectly now that the user defaults to bash upon login!  Thanks again!!!